# Chip32 AU plugin not recognized by Live

Tags: ableton-live, mac, plug-ins, chipsound

<sup>Mac audio question...</sup>

So I downloaded what is supposedly a superbadass 8-bit synth: [Chip32](https://woolyss.com/chipmusic-plugins.php?s=Nintendo)

But Live ain't havin' it.

I'm pretty sure I installed it in the right place:

**Macintosh HD/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components**

I also (for good measure) installed it in this *other* right place:

**Macintosh HD/Users/username/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components**

So with everything in its right place, one would think this Audio Unit plug-in would be recognized by Ableton Live and show up in the menu:

[image]

But, no such luck. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your OSX version no longer supports 32-bit code, therefore your DAW will not read the plugin.